# Log parser - extend

Tags: php, regex, parsing, icecast

I have icecast access log Like this:

```
11.11.111.11 - 5229 [08/May/2018:11:43:38 +0200] "GET /chillout_delicate.ogg HTTP/1.1" 200 36256 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; GT-I9300 Build/JSS15J)" 0
111.111.11.111 - 2510/14 [08/May/2018:11:43:39 +0200] "GET /pub3.ogg HTTP/1.1" 200 36467 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; GT-P5200 Build/KOT49H)" 1
```

First value is IP. Second one, after -,  is user name. Usually it's a number like 2510/14 or 234. I found php file which I try customize.

```
<?php
$ac_arr = file('/var/log/icecast2/access.log');
$astring = join("", $ac_arr);
$astring = preg_replace("/(\n|\r|\t)/", "", $astring);

$records = preg_split("/([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)/", $astring, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
$sizerecs = sizeof($records);

// now split into records
$i = 1;
$each_rec = 0;
while($i<$sizerecs) {
  $ip = $records[$i];
  $all = $records[$i+1];
  // parse other fields
  preg_match("/\[(.+)\]/", $all, $match);
  $access_time = $match[1];
  $all = str_replace($match[1], "", $all);
  preg_match("/\"[A-Z]{3,7} (.[^\"]+)/", $all, $match);
  $http = $match[1];
  $link = explode(" ", $http);
  $all = str_replace("\"[A-Z]{3,7} $match[1]\"", "", $all);
  preg_match("/([0-9]{3})/", $all, $match);
  $success_code = $match[1];
  $all = str_replace($match[1], "", $all);
  preg_match("/\"(.[^\"]+)/", $all, $match);
  $ref = $match[1];
  $all = str_replace("\"$match[1]\"", "", $all);
  preg_match("/\"(.[^\"]+)/", $all, $match);
  $browser = $match[1];
  $all = str_replace("\"$match[1]\"", "", $all);
  preg_match("/([0-9]+\b)/", $all, $match);
  $bytes = $match[1];
  $all = str_replace($match[1], "", $all);
  print("<br>IP: $ip<br>Access Time: $access_time<br>Page: $link[0]<br>Type: $link[1]<br>Success Code: $success_code<br>Bytes Transferred: $bytes<br>Referer: $ref <br>Browser: $browser<hr>");

  // advance to next record
  $i = $i + 2;
  $each_rec++;
}
?>
```

It gives me results

```
IP: xxx.xxx.xx.xx
Access Time: 08/May/2018:11:58:19 +0200
Page: /restaurant.ogg
Type: HTTP/1.1
Success Code: 153
Bytes Transferred: 8
Referer: GET /restaurant.ogg HTTP/1.1
Browser: Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.1.2; IdeaTabA1000-F Build/JZO54K)
```

I have little experience with regex. How can I add to this results  user name? Please, help.

Comment: I don't see where you get the Success code and bytes transfered from.

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/JyINSI/1. But I do not know where to get those transferred bytes either.

Comment: I need only IP,Access Time, Page and User name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this regex:

https://regex101.com/r/ETKSr3/2

It will parse your string as I think you want in one go.

```
$re = '/(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s-\s([\d\/]+)\s\[(.*?)\]\s\"(.*?)\s\/(.*?)\s(.*?)\"\s(\d+)\s(\d+).*?\"(\w+.*?)\"\s(\d+)/m';

$str = '11.11.111.11 - 5229 [08/May/2018:11:43:38 +0200] "GET /chillout_delicate.ogg HTTP/1.1" 200 36256 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; GT-I9300 Build/JSS15J)" 0
111.111.11.111 - 2510/14 [08/May/2018:11:43:39 +0200] "GET /pub3.ogg HTTP/1.1" 200 36467 "-" "Dalvik/1.6.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.4.2; GT-P5200 Build/KOT49H)" 1';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);

// Print the entire match result
var_dump($matches);
```

Comment: Great!. Thank you all, Andreas especially